# create mock-sms Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create a Dockerfile to build a mock-sms image with a tomcat as a basis Image. so I download a .war file which is a snapshot of a mock-sms. This .war file should be unzipped in a folder.

so I have to define a directory which should be mapped to host. but I don't know what that exactly means.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM vfoms-seu.trivadis.com:5000/tomcat-basis-image:7.0.69

MAINTAINER siamak

ARG VERSION=25.0.3-20180227.221248-17

ARG REPOSITORY_URL=http://172.16.19.24:8081/nexus/content/repositories/vodafone-snapshots/com/trivadis/oms/MockOmSms/25.0.3-SNAPSHOT/MockOmSms-$VERSION.war
RUN wget -P /opt/vfoms/home_mocksms/ $REPOSITORY_URL

RUN tar -xvf MockOmSms-$VERSION.war /opt/vfoms/home_mocksms/output

VOLUME /opt/vfoms/home_mocksms/output: (Host)
VOLUME /opt/vfoms/home_mocksms/log: (Host)

EXPOSE 3001

CMD
```

Do you guys have any idea to solve that?

Comment: use `ADD /path/to/local/war  /path/to/docker/war`. More info [in the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

Comment: Thank for answering. I have in my docker folder these folders:
builder, containerd, containers, image, network, overlay2, plugin, runtimes, swarm, tmp, trust, volumes. Where should be the /path/to/docker/war ???